# has anyone done a plugin for an automatic magazine layout?

Tags: automation

before I get my hands dirty, I wanted to ask if someone in the community has done an automatic layout tool for expressionengine?

I am talking about the method here: 
http://alistapart.com/article/magazinelayout

the php code is available, but I think it has no caching and I don't speak php...

any hints welcome!

Answer (score 3):

There is no currently-available add-on for this ... so many variables involved with EE's flexibility.

IMHO, a javascript-based solution - like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) - would make much more sense, especially in the age of responsive design and fluid layouts. This "magazine" approach only makes sense for fixed-width viewports.

Comment: Masonry, that's the javascript solution I was trying to think of this morning. I kept getting stuck at Modernizer and Isotope instead. Misfiring brain. Upvote Derek.

Comment: Another option similar to Masonry is Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). I haven't had a chance to try it myself yet, but I've seen work done by others. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

I've certainly never seen an add-on that does that for EE - that's some deep math. :)  You can run PHP within an php-enabled EE template though. You could also experiment with some of the other great add-ons out there like Assets and CE Image.